# Deployment fails when uploading s3 connector to WSO2ESB

Tags: amazon-s3, connector, wso2-esb

When uploading the Amazon s3 connector zip(https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/8d95de41-91ee-44b4-a428-81f71d523643) to the esb I get the quoted stack trace and the connector does not get added. I have tried this with both a clean v4.8.1 and a v4.9.0, both giving the same error.

Anyone has any idea what the problem is/how to solve it?

```
[2016-04-26 17:20:51,424] ERROR - LibraryArtifactDeployer Deployment of synapse
artifact failed for synapse libray at : -ESB LOCATION-\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\amazons3-connec
tor-1.0.0.zip : Error when resolving Dependencies for lib : {org.wso2.carbon.con
nector}amazons3
org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Error when reso
lving Dependencies for lib : {org.wso2.carbon.connector}amazons3
        at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.searchAndResolveDe
pendencies(LibDeployerUtils.java:244)
        at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.createSynapseLibra
ry(LibDeployerUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer.deploy(LibraryAr
tifactDeployer.java:60)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy
(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngin
e.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoL
ist.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListe
ner.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(Reposito
ryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(Reposito
ryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(S
chedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask
.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxis
Deployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(Car
bonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a small bug from store site you can get connector zip through build code from [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-amazons3.git). it's works fine to me.

```
[2016-04-27 22:43:17,557]  INFO - LibraryArtifactDeployer Synapse Library named '{org.wso2.carbon.connector}amazons3' has been deployed from file :    /home/rajjaz/Documents/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-libs/amazons3-connector-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
[2016-04-27 22:43:20,621]  INFO - SynapseImportFactory Successfully created Synapse Import: amazons3
```

Comment: Sadly this doesnt work for me. What do you mean by jar btw? Because if you want to add a connector you need to upload a zip(not containing a jar) http://i.imgur.com/Nwq32b3.png. Or do you do it a different way? Also note I am able to deploy other connectors, just not this one.

Comment: sorry it's zip file not an jar

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it to work by building it from source.

Comment: Amazon s3 connector zip(https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/8d95de41-91ee-44b4-a428-81f71d523643) now working fine.